# Does protobuf-net support Dictionary when it goes from .proto file to the .cs file? (via protogen.exe)

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In C# using protobuf-net, I would like to keep my protobuf definition in the *.proto* file. (it's used to generate code for other languages, ...)

I know that the Google's implementation of protoc will not generate any Map's in the Java generated code.

However, since protobuf-net supports Dictionaries if I generate the *.proto* from the *.cs* file, I was wondering if it also supported them going from *.proto* to *.cs* file.

eg, in the *.proto* file I have:

```
message KeyValuePair_String_String {
   optional string Key = 1;
   optional string Value = 2;
}
```

Is it possible to pass any argument to the protobuf-net C# protogen.exe compiler so that it creates Dictionaries instead of Lists?

Thanks,
rui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: Not currently.